# Why am I hitting string subscript out of range?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am trying to use this function and I was able to debug and narrow it down to this variable called addrstore. I don't know why it is giving me this error. I have tried variables, set numbers, and such but I can't seem to get it to work without it erroring out on me. I am able to ignore the error and the program seems to work just fine but every time I run this, it gives me the error, "String subscript out of range."

Here is the code

```
void loading(string file){
ifstream object;
BYTE var;
ADDRESS addr;
string input;

object.open(file);
if (!object){
    cout << "ERROR: Could not load " << file << endl;
}
else{
    string line;
    string addrstore;
    cout << "loaded the file " << file << endl;
    while (!object.eof()){
        getline(object, line);
        addr = 0;
        if (line[0] == 'T'){
            for (int x = 1; x < 7; x++){
                addrstore[x - 1] = 0;
                //addrstore[x - 1] = line[x];
            }
            addr = numconvert(addrstore);
        }
        int i = 7;
        while (line.size() != 0 && line[0] == 'T' && i < line.size()){
            input = line[i] + line[i + 1];
            var = numconvert(input);
            PutMem(addr, &var, 0);
            i += 2;
            addr++;
        }
    }
    object.close();
}
}
```

Comment: This is C++, not C. Please update the tags. :)

Comment: ...but I suspect the issue is that you are referring to line[i+1], when line actually has only elements line[0] through line[i-1].

Comment: You are using `line[0]` without checking that your `line` is non-empty. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: The cause of the issue is the line `addrstore[x - 1] = 0;` Since `addrstore` is never initialized to anything, it has size `0` and any index is out of range. Note that @TheBigH is also correct and when you fix the `addrstore` issue, you reference an out-of-bounds index of `line`.

Comment: You only have one line that indexes `addrstore`, it should be pretty obvious that's where the error is.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the string subscript is out of range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize the variable `addrstore` and assign some value to it at any place in your program. This is causing an issue.

Also without assigning value to variable anywhere else how can you access like `addrstore[x - 1]`

Comment: `string addrstore;` and `string addrstore = "";` both initialize `addrstore` to exactly the same value.

Comment: Hence it's not UB, but it's still the problem